# "Screenlock didn't work" error message on "Verify it's you" for Google Password Manager

Tags: google, password

My passwords are kept in https://passwords.google.com.  When I am on my Android 12 / Pixel 5a, I need one of my passwords, and I go to Google Password Manager to get it, Android asks me to "verify it's [me]."  I understand that I need to get past "use [my] screen lock" so Google knows it's me.

I want to use my fingerprint to authenticate - that is fast and simple.  But when I click on the "Continue" button, it says "Screenlock didn't work."  I can click on the "Try Again" button, but the screen lock doesn't work again, and I get caught in an endless loop of being denied.  (There is a login with password option, but my password is long and very random and very slow and tedious to type.) This is very frustrating and keeps me from getting my passwords stored by Google on my Google phone.

What is the solution/fix for this?

Comment: I am able to log in from [my account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/pwd?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpasswords.google.com%2Fpassword%2FmCItEFrzZ6MMpUl2nsmFj5hy_lrH1gcvPbkatjoXGE4%253D%3Fep%3D1&hl=en&sarp=1&scc=1&rart=ANgoxceXQ7PzS9vc88urcPbPH0jsr3_wwCKEkOmNX5KYOLfOTJjVWiD8iUqDXJvpl83994UvSi1LQvQj_T2qvNf4tu3Gry1JXA&TL=AM3QAYa--BD5QA6qzieTLjNwddzslylXoqjH03zvwvYtZ9fhltAP6ZSMGyW2HTIl&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&cid=1&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) using Chrome // I just downloaded [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lft.password.manager.accounts) and it works fine //

Comment: Maybe network issue? Try clearing the app cache and see

Comment: I don't understand the hype of fingerprint, police can force you to unlock so easy. all they need is a finger. I guess when google ask for screen lock PIN/pattern is expected, fingerprint is insecure

Comment: @alecxs I wasn't clear.. doesn't ask for fingerprint, only account password. That's why I downloaded app to verify what OP is saying that it asks for fingerprint. Only password on both web and app

Comment: Related: [Reddit - Screenlock works for everything but passwords.google.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/kymy2y/screenlock_works_for_everything_but/), [Google Support - "Screenlock didn't work" error when logging intk Google account from Samsung S20 Ultra](https://support.google.com/android/thread/111002533/screenlock-didn-t-work-error-when-logging-intk-google-account-from-samsung-s20-ultra)